# iMac not booting after trying to encrypt a folder with Disk Utility

Tags: macos, boot, mac, encryption, disk-utility

So the issue I am currently trying to fix is the following:

My brother in law owns a iMac Late-14. He tried to encrypt a folder using disk utility but failed or such. After that he rebooted the iMac, it was not booting anymore.

It keeps showing up the loading bar, and then freezes.

I tried resetting the SMC, tried booting from an external hard drive with El Capitan on it, that works. But when booted it gives a message that the Macintosh HD couldn't be repaired.

I want to access the files on the MacintoshHD in any way to repair it, or back up important files.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I think it's disaster recovery kit time - DiskWarrior, TechTool Pro, Data Rescue - none of which are free. Lesson learned: backups should be done before you need them, rather than after.

Comment: Have you tried getting into Recovery Mode?  If not, hold down Command (⌘)-R immediately upon restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I got it fixed using an external hard drive. I managed to make a copy of the macintoshHD which it would let me open eventually backing up everything.